# Read string of compound data type from HDF5 in C++

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have a hdf5 compound dataset which was constructed in Python and from which I am trying to read. I have four columns where one is a string of length 1. I manage to read all but the string column. Below is example code where I try to read only the string column:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

typedef struct data_type {
    char string_column[1];
} data_type;

int main ( void )
{
    int NBR_OF_ROWS = 28884;
    H5::H5File file = H5::H5File(MY_FILE, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
    H5::DataSet dataset = H5::DataSet(file.openDataSet(MY_DATASET));

    H5::CompType mtype(sizeof(data_type));
    mtype.insertMember("member", HOFFSET(data_type, string_column),
            H5::PredType::C_S1);
    data_type *data = new data_type[NBR_OF_ROWS];
    dataset.read(data, mtype);

    std::cout << "string column " << data[0].string_column << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles but prints nothing :( I tried to allocate the data array on the heap but to no avail. I'm using g++ on ubuntu.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get your prompt back, or is the program stuck? If so you could add print statements between the other statements to see where the program gets stuck. Or, use a debugger to step through line by line.

Comment: I'm afraid I get the prompt back. Seems the string_column char is just empty. I've tried a few things but no luck. I tried allocating the char[] on the heap for every data_type instance but then I got printouts of gibberish and valgrind complained of invalid reads.

Comment: And you don't get those valgrind errors if you allocate on the stack as in the example provided in your question? The only suspect thing I see is that you use a variable-length array when declaring `data`, as `NBR_OF_ROWS` is not actually a compile-time constant. Variable-length arrays is not part of standard C++, but it may be that `g++` allows it as an extension.

Comment: Yeah the invalid reads from valgrind don't show up with the above code. Aha interesting. I will try to create a fixed-size array to see if it works.

Comment: I tried creating the array dynamically. The string is still empty though :(

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem comes from the string datatype you use. You did not specify the size, you just said *it's a string*.

Try to make a [`H5::StrType`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/classH5_1_1StrType.html#502e6a4895bf51314204179e3f093a7f) of length 1:

```
H5::StrType string_type(H5::PredType::C_S1, 1);
```

then use it in the compound datatype:

```
mtype.insertMember("member", HOFFSET(data_type, string_column), string_type);
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work :( Still prints nothing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @fhal One more thing, try declaring `string_column` of size 2 instead of 1, C strings are zero-terminated so they need one additional cell.